# Make own api as Third party with AWS cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

As we know AWS cognito service provides user management service And we also familier with shopify(the ecommerce store) that provides you it's apis to develop your ecommerce site by sending Auth key and Secret key in headers and it's remain same until i deliberately delete the app. So my question is that how i can do generate the same Auth Key and Secret Key in AWS.I have read many documentations regarding this issue but cant find solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Client Credentials flow in OAuth2 with Cognito UserPools. This allows creating a clientID and clientSecret (Similar to Auth Key and Secret Key) which could be exchanged with Cognito Token Endpoint for Access Token.

Then you can use the Access Token to request for resources in the header and verify it at your API before responding.

Check the article [Server to Server Auth with Amazon Cognito](https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/05/31/server-to-server-auth-with-amazon-cognito/) for more info.

Comment: First of thanks for your reply. Second is there any way to authenticate client to server using cognito. We cant use our clientID and clientSecret at client side because it's to risky.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to build a simple system where each API developer can login (Using Cognito Username & Password) and retrieve the Refresh Token (Which is long-lived). For resource access, the consumer can get a ID token (Using Refresh token) and consume the resources